# How can I set a delay in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, delay, fade, preloader

I have a bit of code that acts as a preloader that displays until all JS has loaded. The only problem is I see the preloader appear over the top of the content coming in to the page.

How do I adjust the code below to fade out the '#loading-mask' div, pause with a blank screen for .5 of a second then fade in my page content?

The primary goal is to stop the two from overlapping

Here's my code:

```
$('#loading-mask').fadeOut();
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loading-mask').fadeOut(500, function() {
    setTimeout(500);
    $('#content').fadeIn()
});
```

Comment: what was `sleep(500)` for?

Comment: I had it as a placeholder and whilst trying to re-remember what sleep is in javascript I accidentally clicked submit too early... whoops.

Comment: `sleep()` is in PHP i think and also in C. Yeah I remember.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fade the loading div away then fade in my content after a pause.